# Work with child elements and a set of containers and targeting

Tags: javascript

I’m attempting to assign a number to child elements depending on the number of elements within a set of containers.

For example, container 1 contains 2 elements so the child elements would be assigned numbers 1 & 2 respectively. Container 2 contains 3 elements so they would be assigned numbers 1, 2 & 3 respectively.

Here is what I’ve got so far but the code is targeting the child elements as a whole, rather than taking into account their containers. I imagine it’s a case of adjusting the targeting?

```
$('.container a.link').each(function (i) {
    $(this).data('linkNumber', { number: ++i }); 
    linkNumberIdent = 'link--' + 'child' + $(this).data('linkNumber').number;
    $(this).addClass(linkNumberIdent);
});
```

So far I’ve tried using `children()` to specify it, but it doesn’t work at all. My thought was that using `children()` would target each child element of the container.

```
$('.container').children('a.link').each(function (i) {
    $(this).data('linkNumber', { number: ++i }); 
    linkNumberIdent = 'link--' + 'child' + $(this).data('linkNumber').number;
    $(this).addClass(linkNumberIdent);
});
```

Please let me know if anyone has any thoughts!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your HTML elements as well to help your futher

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read our [ask] page and then [edit] your question to improve it.  It would be helpful to have a [mcve] (including HTML) so it's easier/faster to others to respond with good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a selector like `$('.container a.link')` you are retrieving all matching elements into one single array so it's more difficult to know which container each element came from and, therefore, how many elements are in each container.

Instead, you can have nested loops for this.  In the first loop, you can just include all the `.containers` and then, for each `.container` get the children (assuming all children are what you want to add numbers to)

You can adjust the selector in the inner `.each()` loop to include only the items you want to number (just in case you do not want to number every child element of a container)

**See demo code below**

```js
// outer loop, grab all containers and for each container
$('.container').each(function(i, el) {
  // grab all children in container and assign a number
  // you can adjust the selector here if you want to include/exclude 
  // other elements in the container (i.e. only <a> or only <li> etc)
  $(el).children().each(function(j, link) {
    // the looping index 'j' starts counting at zero so we assign n+1 to the element
    $(link).data('link-number', j + 1);
    console.log($(link).data('link-number'));  // this line is for verification only, can be deleted 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">three</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="link">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="link">two</a>
</div>
```